# OpenCV draw contours (Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, contour

I run the following code from Jupyter Notebook:

```
import cv2 as cv
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(im, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnt = contours[4]
cv.drawContours(im, contours, 2, (0, 230, 255), 6)
# Show the image with contours
cv.imshow('Contours', im)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

(im is a binary image)
After running this, the Jupyter Kernel dies. What should I change?

Comment: Did you debug the code by separating cells by cells? The code is working. If you want I can explain and share my code as an answer.

Comment: Probably related to the waitKey(0). Wouldn't work in Jupyter.

Comment: @GilPinsky what should be used in Jupyter instead? (I tried without waitKey at all, and it didn't work)

Comment: @obart What do you mean by didn't work? Didn't show? You can try showing the result using matplotlib: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt ,and using plt.imshow(im).

Comment: @GilPinsky Yes, didn't show. I tried using plt.imshow(im), however the image that is displayed is the original one, and I want to display the contours. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here's a workaround. TL;DR: You need to use `im = cv.drawContours(im, contours, 2, (0, 230, 255), 6)` to save the drawn contours and `im = np.expand_dims(im,axis=2).repeat(3,axis=2)` in order to be able to draw colored contours.
The following code draws **all** contours on `im` and shows it using `matplotlib`:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#im an H X W array.
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(im, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
im = np.expand_dims(im, axis=2).repeat(3, axis=2) 
for k, _ in enumerate(contours):
    im = cv.drawContours(im, contours, k, (0, 230, 255), 6)
plt.imshow(im)
```

Comment: The image I have ('im' in the question) is a binary image. The result I want to display is the contours of that binary image. What modifications should I make to the code in your comment in order for it be suitable for binary input image? [and the result should be only the contours]
thanks!

Comment: See my updated answer. You need to make ```im``` a 3-channel image, so use ```np.expand_dims``` and ```repeat``` as shown. If you want only the contours, initialize ```im``` before the ```for``` loop as a zeros ```numpy.ndarray``` with shape H X W X 3.